AWS Amplify deployment permanent "pending" state
Amplify job is in pending state
So GitHub repository and Amplify are connected. When I push anything to the active branches it triggers Amplify (webhook is working correctly), and creates a new deployment, but the build is not started. There are no logs or messages which can point to the problem. I've discovered only one similar problem in Discord, with only one proposition to check Cloudformation for any rollbacks that may prevent the deployment. I've not found such.
Application framework: React.
Backend is not hosted on Amplify.
I've tried to find similar problems and their solutions. I have been looking through Amplify issues, the Discord channel, checking AWS settings and environment variables, searching for any logs, stopping and starting jobs using AWS CLI, and checking permissions.

The solution to the problem is straightforward. There was a problem with the payment and, as an IAM user, I hadn't permission to check this, while stakeholders told me everything was OK. :)

While I was trying to upload and deploy the build zip on amplify.
I faced a similar issue, but payment wasn't a problem in my case.
It was some issue related to permission, I didn't have the required permission to upload the files, therefore it showed that the file was uploaded, and in the next stage it was infinitely waiting in the "pending state".
Here's how I solved it.
Possible solution
I couldn't find a way to cancel the deployment via the console, but I found a way to cancel it using the AWS CLI after searching the AWS documentation.
Here are the steps:
Click on the CLI Icon right next to the search bar.
Once the CLI is opened, follow the below steps
Steps to be followed in the CLI

List Jobs and identify the Job IDs of pending jobs: aws amplify list-jobs --app-id YOUR_APP_ID --branch-name YOUR_BRANCH_NAME
Stop the Job : aws amplify stop-job --app-id YOUR_APP_ID --branch-name YOUR_BRANCH_NAME --job-id YOUR_PENDING_JOB_ID
Repeat the step 2 for all the jobs which are in pending state.

All your pending deployments will be cancelled now.
